# Do players automatically succeed on threshold 1 tests in Shadowrun 5e?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

The "Poor Self Control" negative quality catergory in Run Harder provides the "Compulsive" negative quality, which states,

> The character must make a Composure (2) test to resist the compulsion.
>   The base Karma value is (2 x threshold needed for Composure Test; must
>   be from 1 to 4); then add...[etc]

However, my understanding is that meeting or exceeding a threshold is a success in Shadowrun; as the lowest result on a d6 die is 1, wouldn't players automatically succed on this test? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I guess you've recently switched from SR3??? The system has changed between SR3 and SR4 AFAIK. nvoigt's answer explains how this works now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the dice system of Shadowrun again.

> Composure (2)

This means you roll a composure check and *you need two successes* to be successful.

As an example: you roll 5 dice for this test, they come up 1,3,5,2,3. That's only one success (the 5), therefore you failed the Composure check.

A single die is a success at a 5 or 6, regardless of check. You almost always roll multiple dice (sometimes up to 20-30). But some checks require you to get more successes than your enemy, some require a fixed number. This is one where you are rolling to get a fixed number of successes.